# Overheating of LM1117-3.3 with just 330Ohm load

Tags: voltage-regulator, heat

I am using a LM1117-3.3 Surface Mount device.

I am using 100uF capacitor at input and output. I put a 330Ohm resistor at the end.

My input is 12V.

As soon as I power up the circuit, the LM1117-3.3 Over heats sooo much that it even melts the solder on it instantly, within few seconds. I assumed it was the load pulling too much current. But a 330Ohm load would not pull sooo much current that it melts the solder.

What could be the problem?

[image]

The problem was the bad regulator. I changed the regulator. All worked well for a while but the led did not glow. Thenb I had to simulate a LOAD of 350mA. So I attached a resistor of 10Ohm at the ourput in Series with an Led. The Regulator got over heated and blew up again. Even though the connections were all correct. And the datasheet says the max current that can be pulled is 1A. Then still why is the reg blowing up?

**Note: I am now using the AMS1117-3.3 Regulator**
Following is my schematic:

[image]

Comment: Looks like problem with your connection. Which package are you using? 87mW is the power dissipated by the regulator. Should be something related to wiring or connection.

Comment: *melts the solder* Then your regulator is broken, if it was working correctly and connected correctly it would not get that hot. It has build-in thermal shutdown.

Comment: I am using the SOT-223 package

Comment: @FakeMoustache Then I should definitely assume that the regulator is broken? I did connect it reverse by mistake the 1st time. but just for a few seconds. By reverse I mean,
Vin-----GND(power supply)
GND----VIN(power supply)

Comment: *did connect it reverse by mistake the 1st time* AHA ! If you do not use a **current limited** power supply to limit the current to say 100mA then you can **destroy** such a regulator in 0.001 s. So "just a few seconds" does not help you at all. Next time: use a **current limited power supply**.

Comment: Next time, include that *I did connect it reverse by mistake the 1st time.* in your question because that is **THE** vital clue to the answer !!!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the LED is the right way round?

Comment: What output voltage do you measure?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have it connected incorrectly. Note that the pinout is different from regulators such as LM7805:

[image]

If you put it in a 7805 position there is an internal diode junction that will be forward biased and it will likely be destroyed.

Edit: It's apparent that this is what happened, after which connecting it correctly will result in the damaged chip acting just as you describe.

Comment: No Sir, I cross checked the connection pin diagrams multiple times. The pin connection is correct

Comment: Then you should replace the regulator with a known good one-it may be defective or fake. This cannot happen with a good regulator properly connected, even if the parts outside were really off.

Answer (score 0):

Load current = 3.3V / 330 Ohm = 10mA

Power dissipated in a linear regulator = (Vin - Vout) * Load current

(12V - 3.3V) * 10mA = 8.7V * 10mA = **87mW**

From the datasheet:

[image: LM1117-3.3 Maximum Allowable Power Dissipation vs. Ambient Temperature for SOT-223]

θ_JA is the thermal resistance between the semiconductor die and ambient air. Depending on how much, or how little, copper you have on your PCB footprint to sink the heat away from this part, it can get hot even at a seemingly low power dissipation. If there is hardly any heatsinking on the PCB, the part can get hot enough to melt solder. If it got that hot, it is probably destroyed.

Comment: Then what is the solution? 330Ohm load was just a test. I have to drive a 450mA load in my project with the same regulator. The datasheet says it can output 800mA current.

Comment: @shantanu: ... More heatsinking...

Comment: Use a different component package, like the TO-220 version, and get a heatsink on it.

There is a significant difference in dissipated power depending on input voltage. At 12V in, 3.3V out at 450mA, you will dissipate (12-3.3V)*0.45A = 4W. At 6V in, 3.3V out at 450mA, you will dissipate (6-3.3V)*0.45A = 1.2W. 

The device can only supply 800mA with adequate heatsinking. It is not feasible to heatsink a SOT-23 to dissipate the 4W calculated above.

Comment: Lm1117 should shut down at about 150 C die temperature, which is not enough to melt solder. Something else is wrong.

Comment: Read above, he had destroyed the regulator already by reverse connecting it.

Comment: How do you connect a SOT23 backwards?

Comment: @vofa
(reg) VIN ------- GND (power supply)
(reg) GND --------VIN(power supply)

Comment: When connected like that all the ESD diodes are in forward mode so the chip basically behaves as 2 diodes in series in forward mode. It can only survive this if the current is limited to like 1 A or so. If there is no current limiting it will fry the chip in an instant. Only special chips which are designed for it can survive having their supply reversed.

Comment: @shantanu You could put a reverse-polarity protection diode in series with the power input. It will usefully reduce the voltage going to the regulator by about 0.7 V too (and dissipating about 0.3 W in the process, so the diode will get slightly warm, but that was only going to be dissipated in the regulator otherwise).